# Magento 2 - Conflict in localisation csv file

Tags: module, theme, template, localisation, translate

I understand the general structure of i18n csv files that is like

```
<key_hook>,<translation_of_that_key>
```

but [according to the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html#element-translations-per-module) there is the possibility to add a module restriction:

```
<key_hook>,<translation_of_that_key>, module, <module_vendor>
```

In my case in de_DE.csv (in my custom theme i18n directory) I've used:

```
"Summary", "Zusammenfassung", module, Magento_Review
"Summary", "Kassenübersicht", module, Magento_Checkout
```

The problem is now that if the customer likes to write a review on the single product page, there is still "Kassenübersicht" instead of "Zusammenfassung". Why is that? Does this restriction really work? Do I (really) have to use different original Translation Hooks?

*Magento Verion 2.3.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento's translations are a pain and the documentation for them is even worse.

Theme translations are global and will affect the string regardless of the module, to translate on a per module basis you need to use a translation package. I'm not sure if this is intentional behaviour or if it's a bug that module based translations don't work in the theme.

The main differences between theme translation and translation packages are:

- They support module based translations
- Theme translations are placed in `{theme}/i18n/` whilst translation package are placed in `app/i18n/`
- Translation packages require registration.php and language.xml files

You can find instructions for how to create a translation package [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2). Note that it's optional to gather all the available strings.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess we will overwrite the original Language definition with something like `Summary_Review` and `Summary_Checkout`. Time is money.

Comment: Yeah, I sometimes just change the strings in the template where feasible. I don't like doing it but it's often better than faffing around with broken translations for hours just to change a word.